# Function not satisfying particular testcase

Tags: python, function, unit-testing

My function trim(S) passes every test case except test 2.

Assume that S is a string. Return a string which is the same as string S, but with no blanks at the front or end of the string. For example trim('   dog   ') returns 'dog'. trim('    cat in the hat') returns 'cat in the hat'. Notice that blanks that are not at the beginning or end are left as they are. Example 3: trim('')  and trim('       ') both return the empty string. You must not use recursion. Do not use built-in functions that trim, like rtrim().

Any Solutions?

```
def trim(S) :

    min_index = 0
    max_index = 0
    if S.isspace() == True:
      new_S = ''
      return new_S
    if len(S) == 0:
      new_S = ''
      return new_S
    for ch in S:
      if ch.isspace() == False and min_index == 0:
        min_index = S.index(ch)
    for ch in S:
      if ch.isspace() == False and S.index(ch) > max_index:
        max_index = S.index(ch)
    new_S = S[min_index:max_index+1]
    # print('new_S: ',new_S)
    print('min_index: ',min_index,'max_index: ', max_index)
    return new_S
# --------------------------------------------------------------
# Testing
# --------------------------------------------------------------
class myTests(unittest.TestCase):
 def test1(self):
  self.assertEqual(trim('    dog   '), 'dog')
 def test2(self):
  self.assertEqual(trim('    cat in the hat'), 'cat in the hat')
 def test3(self):
  self.assertEqual(trim(''), '')
 def test4(self):
  self.assertEqual(trim('      '), '')
 def test5(self):
  self.assertEqual(trim(' red green  blue  .'), 'red green  blue  .')


if __name__ == '__main__':
 unittest.main(exit=True)
```

Comment: You're adding a lot of complexity by trying to track the start of letters and the end of letters. Why not run an infinite loop that removes the first character until it hits a letter, then break. Do a second infinite loop removing the last character until it hits a letter and then break.

Also your first two `if` statements can be combined with an or

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the last loop. The call to `S.index(ch)` within that loop is not guaranteed to find the last non-space in the input string. If the final characters of the input are characters that are also not unique in the string, then `max_index` will never get beyond the corresponding indices, just because `S.index(ch)` will return an index pointing to an *earlier* occurrence of that character. This is for instance the case with the second test, where the final word has characters that all have occurred earlier in the string. The last character that is unique, is the "e" at position 13, and so `max_index` will end up being just 13, which is not what you want.

For that last loop you should really iterate in reverse direction, starting from the end of the string, looking for the first non-space character you find as you iterate.

Here is how it could work:

```
def trim(s):
    if not s or s.isspace():
        return ""
    for i, ch in enumerate(s):
        if not ch.isspace():
            break
    for j, ch in enumerate(s[::-1]):
        if not ch.isspace():
            break
    return s[i:len(s)-j]
```